# Unlock codes inactive

Tags: dialer-codes

Why don't the Android secret codes work for any of my android devices, I have two s7 edge phones and two s9 phones with the straight talk wireless unlimited plan, the phones came from Verizon wireless and were transferred over, any reason why?

s9 just downloaded the latest firmware, It didn't work before or after.

```
 Testing Menu. *#*#4636#*#*

 Factory Restore. *#*#7780#*#*

 Camera Information. *#*#34971539#*#*

 Display Info about device. *#*#4636#*#*

 Backup all media files. *#*#273283*255*663282*#*#*

 Completely Wipe device, install stock firmware. *2767*3855#

 Wireless LAN Test. ...
```

Comment: Because Samsung disabled them, and they don't use the stock Android phone app which interprets them, so they would have to build support in for the codes. In some cases, Samsung devices use proprietary special codes, but about the only one that I know that works is *#06# which is pretty generic to display your IMEI number.

Comment: @acejavelin that one don't even work for me, you say they're disabled but there's various articles and videos on the web of them working on s9/s9+

Comment: Perhaps in international or unlocked versions... But there are also several articles out there talking about how the codes do not work. You can always get the app Hidden Menus from the Play Store which can bypass the dialer and talk directly to the framework to open these menus (apps).

Comment: [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo) gives you codes specific to your device ; some may need root to be launched